# Tikz bar plot problem: Missing number, treated as zero \end

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have been trying to plot the figure:

[image]

by using TikZ. However, the code does not compile and I get many errors on line 48, which is \end{axis}, as follows:

```
Dimension too large
Missing number, treated as zero
Missing number, treated as zero \end{axis}
Extra \endcsname \end{axis}
```

I have 3912 data for both "corrected" and "interpolated" data, as shown in the image in the above link. Each bar contains one column for "corrected and one for "interpolated". I want to have a little gap between each column and bar. However, since there are 3912 bars, the gap becomes very small.

The code can be found in below. I had to remove most of the coordinates in the code to be able to post the question.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\newlength\figureheight
\newlength\figurewidth
\setlength\figureheight{4cm}
\setlength\figurewidth{8cm} 
% defining custom colors
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0,0,0.5625}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
scale only axis,
xmin=0, xmax=4500,
ymin=0, ymax=40,
legend style={draw=black,fill=white,align=left},
area legend]
\addplot[ybar,bar width=5.07936507936508e-05\figurewidth,bar shift=-3.17460317460317e-05\figurewidth,fill=mycolor1,draw=mycolor1] plot coordinates{ (1,7.67925776852681) (2,7.89191272713598) (3,7.80049189095382) (4,7.59686636089235) (5,7.51745631713953) (6,7.48541656721179) (7,12.6373914509645) (8,10.7190161710158) (9,7.6817173386498) (10,7.49323026735275) (11,7.25494980046892) (12,7.7730905146054) (13,15.0270536561953) (14,20.4015910110649) (15,3.5109569644315) (16,2.41485830796476) (17,2.78736059942334) (18,7.458073695569) (19,7.6158979046821) (20,7.57443654621311) (21,7.34152203934566) (22,7.22507866556772) (23,7.18974058359779) (24,12.6899675959173) (25,10.7117221284263) (26,7.65284112708195) (27,7.4944601072829) (28,7.38354677101688) (29,7.97020544129491) (30,14.9042131356978) (31,20.1419057971168) (32,4.0059828878528) (33,2.75126110918529) (34,2.5709119537156) (35,7.33072968734785) (36,7.47040119476129) (37,7.40080866087593) (38,7.15717925959866) (39,7.03537238506774) (40,7.01417111934541) (41,15.145731363078) (42,10.9774742839385) (43,7.91615359520869) (44,7.77842728109795) (45,7.73664820982248) (46,10.9693748055796) (47,18.1792553883102) (48,22.9165444515374) (49,18.1624480126299) (50,3.24314697672339) (51,2.99516580751726) (52,7.35542288202923) (53,7.73237968625605) (54,11.5965095143778) (55,11.4062013827679) (56,11.7191233472388) (57,11.4117733474254) (58,7.46394241162696) (59,11.5966259554984) (60,8.49790618063887) (61,8.2508504634656) (62,8.24445697023325) (63,14.4332817251754) (64,35.8373515624242) (65,25.9761339600678) (66,26.3484423004561) (67,4.1106702198142) (68,3.68051396264358) (69,11.0176479049838) (70,10.9321103405229) (71,10.9549591451551) (72,11.0887851969169) (73,11.2984634229199) (74,8.18800612811101) (75,10.7154862029533) (76,32.155600665545) (77,26.3983133497149) (78,9.02457189520993) (79,15.1171340964546) (80,23.3767425630843) (81,29.7533173203289) (82,20.2650116601358) (83,16.5503294583692) (84,26.0636695914866) (85,6.77181133145384) (86,10.7356104760853) (87,10.6959134026698) (88,10.8556261504415) (89,11.660467940214) (90,8.99373087491466) (91,7.90872739739617) (92,7.38024567331697) (93,8.4785387943717) (94,25.1238668264533) (95,17.1804133297583) (96,23.0765557679917) (97,19.5727101288508) (98,16.6367207748339) (99,17.8968317920327) (100,24.5639708235006) (101,16.0494446035713) (102,23.1666730118493) (103,10.723530508449) (104,10.745466764304) (105,11.251408203245) (106,10.0921626473108) (107,11.5072998252888) (108,8.37655302163696) (109,8.02277751908322) (110,7.89636001790077) (111,6.61438288422899) (112,7.59677472946235) (113,15.1787122250653) (114,26.6572727725904) (115,21.0235425072076) (116,12.5324391917295) (117,12.3351438411022) (118,12.6691779574475) (119,12.7126724264412) (120,9.92941604839816) (121,9.53791820792116) (122,9.3905197366545) (123,9.32478813139845) (124,10.1933713510167) (125,7.89958440003049) (126,7.7058952182203) (127,7.40192959267953) (128,16.3954636555399) (129,18.39788073814) (130,14.0177821023947) (131,12.4994433972792) (132,11.4655590352526) (133,10.0479947429511) (134,8.258496560335) (135,9.39953494397581) (136,9.2845947974024) (137,8.98737349878294) (138,8.85334610142407) (139,8.78749616882949) (140,8.77344786397684) (141,9.07654776067787) (142,8.73107321577536) (143,13.727187877742) (144,27.3464010063229) (145,12.3454466560748) (146,10.7385656773577) (147,12.738468050864) (148,15.5841504413289) (149,15.1138135371472) (150,4.1188628062503) (151,20.6000503851565) (152,28.517872150685) (153,24.157884568311) (154,16.9042161171853) (155,12.2332416671923) (156,12.2450350875483) (157,12.3949058430098) (158,11.9531298868871) (159,10.4950729351269) (160,9.75937859380502) (161,14.2497534543551) (162,18.2957840592943) (163,3.42267102948726) (164,3.89006863048656) (165,4.34532008307766) (166,9.80462794298077) (167,13.4444929298179) (168,10.8626544357279) (169,9.18265127769196) (170,8.62527365034936) (171,9.0303781280478) (172,9.16610514539105) (173,9.5195667952341) (174,15.1352102813753) (175,3.07578832843528) (176,4.91103494057773) (177,8.83717776362407) (178,8.01076685167589) (179,5.38149307859497) (180,11.493379567167) (181,12.9915960572903) (182,14.5274890707426) (183,7.98977443639616) (184,8.82286260151406) (185,9.04862368016335) (186,8.96980312650842) (187,8.01349464167493) (188,5.15631859000723) (189,2.66732620614063) (190,3.02698048618063) (191,12.7740155370606) (192,5.13385820198532) (193,5.31265788058696) (194,5.24367094341045) (195,5.49273354502654) (196,5.05313131636797) (197,7.04344740077222) (198,6.78447601121456) (199,5.94023845919936) (200,13.5058162628521) (201,4.43122698565505) (202,2.29282691848472) (203,2.62783205490409) (204,2.55337345158217) (205,2.46775461033322) (206,2.77023361875713) (207,13.6633631064085) (208,7.04964885472821) (209,6.82884887579698) (210,6.86142853427944) (211,2.69309365749078) (212,2.70698483868788) (213,2.80256507031715) (214,2.53463958485699) (215,2.4771623034084) (216,2.37423941610727) (217,2.28347877619665) (218,2.2604598420006) (219,2.34957658006529) (220,2.9555452563669) (221,7.32909082557967) (222,9.98307747094892) (223,7.18696193429116) (224,7.23299638542514) (225,7.31466547255909) (226,9.91113214137525) (227,2.86659012490543) (228,2.50801631809679) (229,7.99787457264886) (230,6.21409681911644) (231,4.8016009522661) (232,6.86278800147492) (233,12.5270576427198) (234,2.21778393498543) (235,2.13902635467258) (236,1.70519040367763) (237,4.53098872343159) (238,6.704205811603) (239,9.56039590460022) (240,7.50684047859395) (241,4.65575873016157) (242,5.94931702357858) (243,2.34902078847186) (244,1.66325551083391) (245,2.18170413237767) (246,3.44643610574025) (247,1.77523373213968) (248,1.76190775488472) (249,3.98952208200991) (250,7.02631225631318) (251,7.22472007337518) (252,6.60997769386235) (253,6.28807230091759) (254,6.1684727019719) (255,5.8651947063736) (256,5.79723612241028) (257,10.9820054651619) (258,5.83638279945002) (259,2.89423647889987) (260,2.8308941396979) (261,6.76958940317923) (262,21.5030755288965) (263,16.3749904148227) (264,2.17217865781971) (265,1.79000606169705) (266,3.64436666148415) (267,6.78120085103903) (268,6.85003157599207) (269,6.52192529142848) (270,6.21483424951281) (271,6.06549996714627) (272,5.88109483416021) (273,6.10427136319069) (274,10.3668186109438) (275,6.67732913107573) (276,6.34434851123816) (277,11.5420896441039) (278,6.95690908130888) (279,22.1546807366681) (280,33.5032005568846) (281,2.60513138783838) (282,1.94111378984568) (283,3.94513941438485) (284,6.59853630969325) (285,6.60297703041445) (286,6.85125215354739) (287,6.52497733944047) (288,6.37140996803559) (289,6.25836949598256) (290,6.81832235906524) (291,10.5006469045051) (292,7.10187901430344) (293,6.78890591158479) (294,6.72994466580288) (295,11.0144684492729) (296,22.6523333537359) (297,23.1174485042011) (298,3.25658923701601) (299,2.27015328693375) (300,4.28189089654266) (301,6.4921269376934) (302,6.47313322443297) (303,6.59362454277515) (304,7.12878358662848) (305,6.71423472746923) (306,6.60343737320629) (307,6.73071983998315) (308,11.0462125307379) (309,7.6237912574102) (310,7.40452087914546) (311,8.53768364538727) (312,11.0735775358602) (313,26.26748571383) (314,19.2753632797963) (315,4.25414201203332) (316,2.97077179217249) (317,4.54508352883482) (318,6.47222629771275) (319,6.45342624101562) (320,6.58286526801928) (321,6.90919090038583) (322,10.9340133750194) (323,11.1413850419962) (324,8.85020254649959) (325,14.6231271326818) (326,8.39609860579205) (327,8.1102252163042) (328,14.3815303915823) (329,18.7856223765643) (330,25.737371071741) (331,16.4191668957377) (332,24.7851406076717) (333,4.01343447929937) (334,3.54655597292447) (335,6.60707282232936) (336,6.70851356161361) (337,10.412478397985) (338,10.3652901239214) (339,10.6764487210627) (340,8.34883496792358) (341,9.43874978622703) (342,10.732723992119) (343,20.9671792729818) (344,22.2796831193432) (345,26.2689350815855) (346,22.0555092056697) (347,16.2589625720906) (348,14.1913148111443) (349,16.6950287239065) (350,7.66909672127485) (351,6.81492107255328) (352,10.1446291316534) (353,10.0258595156777) (354,10.1116769914944) (355,10.3492596672605) (356,9.67403570343042) (357,8.26023065841463) (358,7.18650434291815) (359,6.31336922578616) (3677,1.17056094602306) (3678,7.76162697260445) (3679,0.988725545762644) (3855,15.3642128883453) (3856,20.4793606616793) (3857,7.56608975352655) (3858,7.87524992441182) (3859,18.0465067586201) (3860,5.53485145655565) (3861,0.726950765606692) (3862,1.12930594369344) (3863,3.60736989120596) (3864,4.71795609493023) (3865,4.34805667744069) (3866,5.69713988933337) (3867,5.90600834191925) (3868,5.95175519735194) (3869,5.87357955699512) (3870,0.741915601522068) (3871,1.22878670257979) (3872,3.65387280443578) (3873,7.50699546931154) (3874,5.9195011959312) (3875,5.73510678810434) (3876,5.63419669288746) (3877,0.770239080610968) (3878,2.16193303019363) (3879,5.11853035978307) (3880,2.91418834696716) (3881,2.51934416241699) (3882,4.92105736597358) (3883,5.47429193798979) (3884,16.7284103378678) (3885,23.2435398544722) (3886,23.4894870807394) (3887,23.8363726003677) (3888,21.5039206954628) (3889,0.831682722260771) (3890,2.05752917245903) (3891,3.07767020638021) (3892,3.90285703343124) (3893,7.35556303251671) (3894,1.79387143391482) (3895,1.38742651655297) (3896,1.23876828123597) (3897,1.20750299333843) (3898,2.7851331449517) (3899,5.63499757554771) (3900,2.99632029834448) (3901,0.907866809300416) (3902,1.87361366818838) (3903,2.53153898068471) (3904,3.95290157640666) (3905,4.20588106433053) (3906,1.24534849313576) (3907,4.99987975960946) (3908,1.24102364401449) (3909,1.2680301186678) (3910,2.30506899961464) (3911,1.89583636267601) (3912,7.1851838917926) (3913,0) (3914,0) (3915,0) (3916,0) (3917,0) (3918,0) (3919,0) (3920,0) (3921,0) (3922,0) (3923,0) (3924,0) (3925,0) (3926,0) (3927,0) (3928,0) (3929,0) (3930,0) (3931,0) (3932,0) (3933,0) (3934,0) (3935,0) (3936,0) (3937,0) (3938,0) (3939,0) (3940,0) (3941,0) (3942,0) (3943,0) (3944,0) (3945,0) (3946,0) (3947,0) (3948,0) (3949,0) (3950,0) (3951,0) (3952,0) (3953,0) (3954,0) (3955,0) (3956,0) (3957,0) (3958,0) (3959,0) (3960,0) (3961,0) (3962,0) (3963,0) (3964,0) (3965,0) (3966,0) (3967,0) (3968,0) (3969,0) (3970,0) (3971,0) (3972,0) (3973,0) (3974,0) (3975,0) (3976,0) (3977,0) (3978,0) (3979,0) (3980,0) (3981,0) (3982,0) (3983,0) (3984,0) (3985,0) (3986,0) (3987,0) (3988,0) (3989,0) (3990,0) (3991,0) (3992,0) (3993,0) (3994,0) (3995,0) (3996,0) (3997,0) (3998,0) (3999,0) (4000,0) (4001,0) (4002,0) (4003,0) (4004,0) (4005,0) (4006,0) (4007,0) (4008,0) (4009,0) (4010,0) (4011,0) (4012,0) (4013,0) (4014,0) (4015,0) (4016,0) (4017,0) (4018,0) (4019,0) (4020,0) (4021,0) (4022,0) (4023,0) (4024,0) (4025,0) (4026,0) (4027,0) (4028,0) (4029,0) (4030,0) (4031,0) (4032,0) (4033,0) (4034,0) (4035,0) (4036,0) (4037,0) (4038,0) (4039,0) (4040,0) (4041,0) (4042,0) (4043,0) (4044,0) (4045,0) (4046,0) (4047,0) (4048,0) (4049,0) (4050,0) (4051,0) (4052,0) (4053,0) (4054,0) (4055,0) (4056,0) (4057,0) (4058,0) (4059,0) (4060,0) (4061,0) (4062,0) (4063,0) (4064,0) (4065,0) (4066,0) (4067,0) (4068,0) (4069,0) (4070,0) (4071,0) (4072,0) (4073,0) (4074,0) (4075,0) (4076,0) (4077,0) (4078,0) (4079,0) (4080,0) (4081,0) (4082,0) (4083,0) (4084,0) (4085,0) (4086,0) (4087,0) (4088,0) (4089,0) (4090,0) (4091,0) (4092,0) (4093,0) (4094,0) (4095,0) (4096,0) (4097,0) (4098,0) (4099,0) (4100,0) (4101,0) (4102,0) (4103,0) (4104,0) (4105,0) (4106,0) (4107,0) (4108,0) (4109,0) (4110,0) (4111,0) (4112,0) (4113,0) (4114,0) (4115,0) (4116,0) (4117,0) (4118,0) (4119,0) (4120,0) (4121,0) (4122,0) (4123,0) (4124,0) (4125,0) (4126,0) (4127,0) (4128,0) (4129,0) (4130,0) (4131,0) (4132,0) (4133,0) (4134,0) (4135,0) (4136,0) (4137,0) (4138,0) (4139,0) (4140,0) (4141,0) (4142,0) (4143,0) (4144,0) (4145,0) (4146,0) (4147,0) (4148,0) (4149,0) (4150,0) (4151,0) (4152,0) (4153,0) (4154,0) (4155,0) (4156,0) (4157,0) (4158,0) (4159,0) (4160,0) (4161,0) (4162,0) (4163,0) (4164,0) (4165,0) (4166,0) (4167,0) (4168,0) (4169,0) (4170,0) (4171,0) (4172,0) (4173,0) (4174,0) (4175,0) (4176,0) (4177,0) (4178,0) (4179,0) (4180,0) (4181,0) (4182,0) (4183,0) (4184,0) (4185,0) (4186,0) (4187,0) (4188,0) (4189,0) (4190,0) (4191,0) (4192,0) (4193,0) (4194,0) (4195,0) (4196,0) (4197,0) (4198,0) (4199,0) (4200,0) (4201,0) };

\addlegendentry{Corrected};

\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
forget plot
]
coordinates{
 (0,0)(4500,0) 
};
\addplot[ybar,bar width=5.07936507936508e-05\figurewidth,bar shift=3.17460317460317e-05\figurewidth,fill=red!50!black,draw=red!50!black] plot coordinates{ (1,0.0857771713961686) (2,0.37170090675354) (3,0.37170090675354) (4,0.514662885665893) (5,0.657624848627001) (6,0.486070489883423) (7,0.943548583984373) (8,0.943548583984373) (9,1.08651056289673) (10,1.08651056289673) (11,2.45894521078186) (12,1.22947254180908) (13,1.22947254180908) (14,1.37243450477019) (15,2.01576323634635) (16,2.30168707769543) (17,3.98863778114325) (18,0.0857771713961686) (19,0.37170090675354) (20,0.37170090675354) (21,0.514662885665893) (22,0.657624848627001) (23,0.486070489883423) (24,0.943548583984373) (25,0.943548583984373) (26,1.08651056289673) (27,1.08651056289673) (28,2.45894521078186) (29,1.22947254180908) (30,1.22947254180908) (31,1.37243450477019) (32,2.01576323634635) (33,2.30168707769543) (34,3.98863778114325) (35,0.0857771713961686) (36,0.37170090675354) (37,0.37170090675354) (38,0.514662885665893) (39,0.657624848627001) (40,0.486070489883423) (41,0.943548583984373) (42,0.943548583984373) (43,1.08651056289673) (44,1.08651056289673) (45,2.45894521078186) (46,1.22947254180908) (47,1.22947254180908) (48,1.37243450477019) (49,2.01576323634635) (50,2.30168707769543) (51,3.98863778114325) (52,0.0857771713961686) (53,0.37170090675354) (54,0.37170090675354) (55,0.514662885665893) (56,0.657624848627001) (57,0.486070489883423) (58,0.943548583984373) (59,0.943548583984373) (60,1.08651056289673) (61,1.08651056289673) (62,2.45894521078186) (63,1.22947254180908) (64,1.22947254180908) (65,1.37243450477019) (66,2.01576323634635) (67,2.30168707769543) (68,3.98863778114325) (69,0.0857771713961686) (70,0.37170090675354) (71,0.37170090675354) (72,0.514662885665893) (73,0.657624848627001) (74,0.486070489883423) (75,0.943548583984373) (76,0.943548583984373) (77,1.08651056289673) (78,1.08651056289673) (79,2.45894521078186) (80,1.22947254180908) (81,1.22947254180908) (82,1.37243450477019) (83,2.01576323634635) (84,2.30168707769543) (85,3.98863778114325) (86,0.0857771713961686) (87,0.37170090675354) (88,0.37170090675354) (89,0.514662885665893) (90,0.657624848627001) (91,0.486070489883423) (92,0.943548583984373) (93,0.943548583984373) (94,1.08651056289673) (95,1.08651056289673) (96,2.45894521078186) (97,1.22947254180908) (98,1.22947254180908) (99,1.37243450477019) (100,2.01576323634635) (101,2.30168707769543) (102,3.98863778114325) (103,0.0857771713961686) (104,0.37170090675354) (105,0.37170090675354) (106,0.514662885665893) (107,0.657624848627001) (108,0.486070489883423) (109,0.943548583984373) (110,0.943548583984373) (111,1.08651056289673) (112,1.08651056289673) (113,2.45894521078186) (114,1.22947254180908) (115,1.22947254180908) (116,1.37243450477019) (117,2.01576323634635) (118,2.30168707769543) (119,3.98863778114325) (120,0.128670417431064) (121,0.371700908611683) (122,0.371713702192793) (123,0.515646888371417) (124,0.658582666168217) (125,0.842472853382313) (126,0.587829211718545) (127,1.08374308510228) (128,1.29073509569998) (129,1.65929121282388) (130,2.19783756586073) (131,1.23659945761059) (132,1.52265448304027) (133,2.3016909065088) (134,3.9886378998538) (135,0.350963417213423) (136,0.371701129724422) (137,0.374353852289151) (138,0.711726641089195) (139,0.829222688908263) (140,0.840732258004388) (141,1.00884832413784) (142,0.832621868716074) (143,1.20937421671182) (144,1.47190710961749) (145,18.478820618296) (146,1.79529502297713) (147,2.40376294365805) (148,20.681465663036) (149,2.30185977522151) (150,4.04648644038455) (151,0.629737608178383) (152,0.371700911754683) (153,0.529500613390888) (154,0.710057341570466) (155,0.845487222504616) (156,0.48890766969229) (157,0.950788587724863) (158,1.0374266249788) (159,1.26873824568146) (160,1.4161411889583) (161,24.4628620404755) (162,1.71326241736784) (163,26.3534162470101) (164,4.18400271913613) (165,4.31950040425114) (166,0.404882449799613) (167,0.373916149073277) (168,0.372798074091461) (169,0.514871063965539) (170,0.657826556046644) (171,0.486139637904457) (172,0.943604744366064) (173,1.07058766919736) (174,1.33931249064209) (175,1.49786329803125) (176,2.9494679782515) (177,2.75822895469853) (178,3.42530877441) (179,3.82283392313509) (180,4.31655521208642) (181,2.46000654449267) (182,0.520154670757331) (183,0.384496213552928) (184,0.514664374511055) (185,0.65762485055987) (186,0.486163705529906) (187,0.943748396494717) (188,0.944005273911249) (189,1.08717384295516) (190,3.56971101437709) (191,3.34486627886455) (192,3.13636876384801) (193,2.94017663703107) (194,2.92568262873265) (195,3.9801682847933) (196,31.7969226205309) (197,2.17870547631467) (198,2.14825988901499) (199,2.30907396447702) (200,4.40897103760043) (201,0.661631093687817) (202,0.519185209331526) (203,0.977409448980571) (204,0.959022101595511) (205,1.14401867556952) (206,4.12114260478272) (207,4.18987016673044) (208,3.88137182709741) (209,3.81447564131224) (210,3.84761330955003) (211,0.67805163643205) (212,1.45229950817788) (213,1.92340816916509) (214,3.98287041072024) (215,4.05400878302513) (216,4.39042635820324) (217,4.25541077022646) (218,4.74270355195921) (219,3.96164869526116) (220,4.44294686465345) (221,4.34314664460631) (222,3.99647588829574) (223,3.96096726976468) (224,8.12146767650043) (225,6.26434575556606) (226,2.54445636132955) (227,0.670874815751292) (228,0.92928598973983) (229,1.34229780593842) (230,3.83865767376009) (231,3.7433098579243) (232,3.78758450889359) (233,4.24100151426012) (234,4.41523199416033) (235,4.71062252558983) (236,4.80718798859805) (237,4.6059818100425) (238,4.24855227613271) (239,4.27278818727676) (240,0.670493193611664) (241,0.92206574418263) (242,1.18359253991338) (243,3.42726375922851) (244,3.48065043035123) (245,3.79896232492484) (246,4.51115075359547) (247,4.5892917158432) (248,5.12409450730911) (249,4.88148253205015) (250,0.328812547162139) (251,0.614736270904544) (252,0.614736270904544) (253,0.757698249816897) (254,0.900660224392972) (255,0.729105854034427) (256,2.31599006882705) (257,2.08724684537537) (258,2.05865171064068) (259,2.07294790257145) (260,2.21590984517898) (261,2.24450223500099) (262,1.47250790596008) (263,1.85850502360989) (264,1.75843167697875) (265,2.05865171064068) (266,3.74560241699225) (267,0.328812547162139) (268,0.614736270904544) (269,0.614736270904544) (270,0.757698249816897) (271,0.900660224392972) (272,0.729105854034427) (273,2.3446530038069) (274,2.10156987530019) (275,2.05865184456522) (276,2.07294790257145) (277,2.21590984517898) (278,2.24450223500099) (279,1.47250790596008) (280,1.85850502360989) (281,1.75843167697875) (282,2.05865171064068) (283,3.74560241699225) (284,0.328812547162139) (285,0.614736270904544) (286,0.614736270904544) (287,0.757698249816897) (288,0.900660224392972) (289,0.729105854034427) (290,2.35913106696407) (291,2.10163156153022) (292,2.05865382295791) (293,2.07294790257145) (294,2.21590984517898) (295,2.24450223500099) (296,1.47250790596008) (297,1.85850502360989) (298,1.75843167697875) (299,2.05865171064068) (300,3.74560241699225) (301,0.328812547162139) (302,0.614736270904544) (303,0.614736270904544) (304,0.757698249816897) (305,0.900660224392972) (306,0.729105854034427) (307,2.33032275371948) (308,2.08725116231042) (309,2.05865171064068) (310,2.07294790257145) (311,2.21590984517898) (312,2.24450223500099) (313,1.47250790596008) (314,1.85850502360989) (315,1.75843167697875) (316,2.05865171064068) (317,3.74560241699225) (318,0.328812547162139) (319,0.614736270904544) (320,0.614736270904544) (321,0.757698249816897) (322,0.900660224392972) (323,0.729105854034427) (324,2.31598319519688) (325,2.08724409450222) (326,2.05865171064068) (327,2.07294790257145) (328,2.21590984517898) (329,2.24450223500099) (330,1.47250790596008) (331,1.85850502360989) (332,1.75843167697875) (333,2.05865171064068) (334,3.74560241699225) (335,0.328812547162139) (336,0.614736270904544) (337,0.614736270904544) (338,0.757698249816897) (339,0.900660224392972) (340,0.729105854034427) (341,2.31598319519688) (342,2.08724409450222) (343,2.05865171064068) (344,2.07294790257145) (345,2.21590984517898) (346,2.24450223500099) (347,1.47250790596008) (348,1.85850502360989) (349,1.75843167697875) (350,2.05865171064068) (351,3.74560241699225) (352,0.328812547162139) (353,0.614736270904544) (354,0.614736270904544) (355,0.757698249816897) (356,0.900660224392972) (357,0.729105854034427) (358,2.31598319519688) (3667,1.37749244286698) (3668,6.17101278056198) (3669,0.960648510452717) (3670,4.19673605154273) (3671,4.34758444016802) (3843,16.541842670106) (3844,3.46554361103028) (3845,0.028592395782471) (3846,0.643328666687021) (3847,0.816632064125021) (3848,3.97597789901411) (3849,4.41979795670098) (3850,4.51979904860356) (3851,3.52395191336701) (3852,5.13391980643585) (3853,6.58698424021472) (3854,10.1823717680526) (3855,4.78815757123361) (3856,4.77207355574988) (3857,4.73341692763817) (3858,4.97334058419354) (3859,3.99267879698806) (3860,3.5461644493562) (3861,0.534333703014589) (3862,3.52781425521102) (3863,3.63509628424217) (3864,3.94666163456782) (3865,2.83183771305953) (3866,5.86812724490104) (3867,6.61321232802947) (3868,6.79097587016832) (3869,3.71679142279752) (3870,2.77613596806778) (3871,3.23000594649249) (3872,3.3490415726172) (3873,3.24064527378281) (3874,5.29718908531967) (3875,5.57612133810593) (3876,6.15931952451165) (3877,2.43265198750192) (3878,2.89648625339152) (3879,3.04728272479365) (3880,1.73899362091413) (3881,6.33569893646211) (3882,4.40913256737965) (3883,4.3086735346449) (3884,4.81302902098463) (3885,5.16336330422254) (3886,4.67647705787662) (3887,4.46792397352744) (3888,4.82448525774102) (3889,2.29529271172415) (3890,2.60751765693561) (3891,2.54787521485829) (3892,1.41126826415526) (3893,5.6104964121194) (3894,0.819372567047289) (3895,2.25583939473055) (3896,3.77418386308701) (3897,1.62202586748445) (3898,3.08812619705241) (3899,4.22298349930722) (3900,3.3491205739083) (3901,2.01892967162624) (3902,2.33959396886149) (3903,1.56953363354383) (3904,1.31761579421194) (3905,0.979227908468461) (3906,1.00625872629749) (3907,1.05156783693187) (3908,1.06863595568653) (3909,1.070505288966) (3910,1.36159049398829) (3911,1.23819247179137) (3912,3.48182549820829) (3913,0) (3914,0) (3915,0) (3916,0) (3917,0) (3918,0) (3919,0) (3920,0) (3921,0) (3922,0) (3923,0) (3924,0) (3925,0) (3926,0) (3927,0) (3928,0) (3929,0) (3930,0) (3931,0) (3932,0) (3933,0) (3934,0) (3935,0) (3936,0) (3937,0) (3938,0) (3939,0) (3940,0) (3941,0) (3942,0) (3943,0) (3944,0) (3945,0) (3946,0) (3947,0) (3948,0) (3949,0) (3950,0) (3951,0) (3952,0) (3953,0) (3954,0) (3955,0) (3956,0) (3957,0) (3958,0) (3959,0) (3960,0) (3961,0) (3962,0) (3963,0) (3964,0) (3965,0) (3966,0) (3967,0) (3968,0) (3969,0) (3970,0) (3971,0) (3972,0) (3973,0) (3974,0) (3975,0) (3976,0) (3977,0) (3978,0) (3979,0) (3980,0) (3981,0) (3982,0) (3983,0) (3984,0) (3985,0) (3986,0) (3987,0) (3988,0) (3989,0) (3990,0) (3991,0) (3992,0) (3993,0) (3994,0) (3995,0) (3996,0) (3997,0) (3998,0) (3999,0) (4000,0) (4001,0) (4002,0) (4003,0) (4004,0) (4005,0) (4006,0) (4007,0) (4008,0) (4009,0) (4010,0) (4011,0) (4012,0) (4013,0) (4014,0) (4015,0) (4016,0) (4017,0) (4018,0) (4019,0) (4020,0) (4021,0) (4022,0) (4023,0) (4024,0) (4025,0) (4026,0) (4027,0) (4028,0) (4029,0) (4030,0) (4031,0) (4032,0) (4033,0) (4034,0) (4035,0) (4036,0) (4037,0) (4038,0) (4039,0) (4040,0) (4041,0) (4042,0) (4043,0) (4044,0) (4045,0) (4046,0) (4047,0) (4048,0) (4049,0) (4050,0) (4051,0) (4052,0) (4053,0) (4054,0) (4055,0) (4056,0) (4057,0) (4058,0) (4059,0) (4060,0) (4061,0) (4062,0) (4063,0) (4064,0) (4065,0) (4066,0) (4067,0) (4068,0) (4069,0) (4070,0) (4071,0) (4072,0) (4073,0) (4074,0) (4075,0) (4076,0) (4077,0) (4078,0) (4079,0) (4080,0) (4081,0) (4082,0) (4083,0) (4084,0) (4085,0) (4086,0) (4087,0) (4088,0) (4089,0) (4090,0) (4091,0) (4092,0) (4093,0) (4094,0) (4095,0) (4096,0) (4097,0) (4098,0) (4099,0) (4100,0) (4101,0) (4102,0) (4103,0) (4104,0) (4105,0) (4106,0) (4107,0) (4108,0) (4109,0) (4110,0) (4111,0) (4112,0) (4113,0) (4114,0) (4115,0) (4116,0) (4117,0) (4118,0) (4119,0) (4120,0) (4121,0) (4122,0) (4123,0) (4124,0) (4125,0) (4126,0) (4127,0) (4128,0) (4129,0) (4130,0) (4131,0) (4132,0) (4133,0) (4134,0) (4135,0) (4136,0) (4137,0) (4138,0) (4139,0) (4140,0) (4141,0) (4142,0) (4143,0) (4144,0) (4145,0) (4146,0) (4147,0) (4148,0) (4149,0) (4150,0) (4151,0) (4152,0) (4153,0) (4154,0) (4155,0) (4156,0) (4157,0) (4158,0) (4159,0) (4160,0) (4161,0) (4162,0) (4163,0) (4164,0) (4165,0) (4166,0) (4167,0) (4168,0) (4169,0) (4170,0) (4171,0) (4172,0) (4173,0) (4174,0) (4175,0) (4176,0) (4177,0) (4178,0) (4179,0) (4180,0) (4181,0) (4182,0) (4183,0) (4184,0) (4185,0) (4186,0) (4187,0) (4188,0) (4189,0) (4190,0) (4191,0) (4192,0) (4193,0) (4194,0) (4195,0) (4196,0) (4197,0) (4198,0) (4199,0) (4200,0) (4201,0) };

\addlegendentry{Interpolated};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Could someone please help me? Thanks.

Comment: This problem comes from your `bar width` and `bar shift` settings. You need to separate the factors with `*`, and the first factors are too small: Setting `bar width=5e-4*\figurewidth,bar shift=-3e-4*\figurewidth` instead works. I guess you're trying to make sure that the bars don't overlap? In that case, you should probably use the `ycomb` style instead of `ybar`, or use `ybar interval`. A bar width of 0.0004cm is too small for any practical purposes. Could you edit your question to explain what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @Jake I have modified the question in the post. I also tried to insert * in front of bar width and bar shift but it did not work.

Comment: The gap not only becomes very small, it becomes invisible on virtually any output device (a computer screen has a width of something like 1280 pixels, so you can't even show all the bars, let alone any gaps in between). I would suggest going with `ycomb`.

Comment: You have to insert `*` *and* make the value something like ten times larger.

Comment: Thanks $Jake. ycomb worked. I modified \addplot to \addplot+[ycomb] coordinates{ .... How can I remove the circles from the comb and change them to a simple line? I am asking this because the figure is very difficult to understand with those markers at the end of each comb.

Comment: You can use `\addplot +[ycomb, no markers] ...`

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help. I am very impressed how quickly you helped me.

Answer (score 2):

Your bars have a width of `0.0004cm`, which is too small for any practical purposes. For dense data like this, you should consider using a `ycomb` plot. You can change the plot style by replacing

```
\addplot[ybar,bar width=5...]
```

with

```
\addplot +[ycomb, no markers]
```